# get Dropbox file PERMANENT URL when upload

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, dropbox

```
var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
                                            folder + "/" + file,
                                             Dropbox.Api.Files.WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
                                            body: mem);

                                        var urlHelper = await dbx.Files.GetTemporaryLinkAsync(updated.PathDisplay);
                                        house.MainImage = urlHelper.Link;
```

This code is working. `urlHelper.Link` give me ImageUrl but This url is temporary. After one day This url is not working.

For example: i set database this url yesterday: https://uc278f948a5c22f08d40d0a49484.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/B8u3K6GDYJZ_aliHLEpCzC8PvGZ9ERM8i9oHUAjFcbWFNK5Jjo50dg127AxfgWVozaphH6JQOvdsutWXpd0VZlCEXXWEttLjezEHQ6c87smtZxxfj8jLw1rZaqlK8P7kJnQSs1EMQ4n3YWWuYXTrN-xerpCvPiUWOZh-K_NbO0FDzlfKHsjcd9rgasGJelzIjnw/file

This was working yesterday. But not now.

How can i get permanent URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, the links returned by [`GetTemporaryLinkAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/gh-pages/obj/api/Dropbox.Api.Files.Routes.FilesUserRoutes.html#Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_GetTemporaryLinkAsync_System_String_) are not permanent and are only valid for a few hours.

If you need a non-expiring link, you can use [`CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync`](https://%60CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync%60) instead. Note that the shared links returned by that method point to an HTML preview page by default and not the file content. You can [modify those links for direct file content access as documented here](https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download) though.